# Выравнивание по вертикали в layout, android

Tags: android, android-layout

Вот моя программа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть единственный layout в программе

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.achess.DrawTest
            android:id="@+id/drawTest"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:minHeight="25dip"
            android:text="Начать сначала"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Шахматную доску рисует этот кусок кода:

```
 <com.example.achess.DrawTest
                android:id="@+id/drawTest"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы доска была посередине экрана, а остальная часть экрана был залита например черным. Кнопку я потом уберу в выезжающее слева меню.

Comment: Используйте `FrameLayout` вместо `LinearLayout` и у `DrawTest` добавьте атрибут `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gravity center нужно добавить для контейнера

Comment: android:gravity="center" добавила в LinearLayout. Это не помогло

Comment: можно получить доступ к вашему team viwer?

Comment: android:gravity="center" добавила также в <com.example.achess.DrawTest>. Также нет рузультата

Comment: можно, только я запускаю отладку на реальном телефоне. Эмулятор не работает что-то

Comment: скорей всего проблема в вашем классе DrawTest, так как он отвечает за отображение плиток на дисплее. так нельзя точно сказать причину, нужно смотреть

Comment: напишите данные для подключения на почту martsinkevych@mail.ru

Comment: как  можно дать вам пароль к TV? не могу сообщение вам написать.

Comment: для доступа мне нужен ваш ид и пароль с приложения теам вивер. отправьте мне их на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com или на martsinkevych@mail.ru

Comment: отправила вам письмо

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` не будет центрировать элементы по вертикали в вертикальном `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

В вертикальном `LinearLayout` нельзя сделать центрирование по вертикали. Используйте другой контейнер, например `FrameLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.achess.DrawTest
            android:id="@+id/drawTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:minHeight="25dip"
            android:text="Начать сначала"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: попробую ваше решение также, спасибо